# IBM MQ docker on mac : unable login uisng user added via FROM mq RUN useradd alice -G mqm

Tags: macos, docker, ibm-mq

added user via

```
Dockerfile FROM mq RUN useradd alice -G mqm && \
    echo alice:passw0rd | chpasswd COPY config.mqsc /etc/mqm/
```

**Logs shows**

IBM MQ queue manager 'QM1' starting.
The queue manager is associated with installation 'Installation1'.
5 log records accessed on queue manager 'QM1' during the log replay phase.

Log replay for queue manager 'QM1' complete.
Transaction manager state recovered for queue manager 'QM1'.

### IBM MQ queue manager 'QM1' started using V9.0.4.0.

Configuring app user

### The setmqaut command completed successfully.

however, unable to login

```
url -k "https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/rest/v1/login" -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"username\":\"alice\",\"password\":\"passw0rd\"}"
```

**Error:**

```
{"error": [{
  "action": "Provide valid credentials or use another form of authentication such as a client certificate.",
  "completionCode": "0",
  "explanation": "The REST API request failed due to incorrect username and password credentials.",
  "message": "MQWB0105E: Login failed.",
  "msgId": "MQWB0105E",
  "reasonCode": "0",
  "type": "rest"
```

Comment: What does the AMQERR01.LOG show?

Comment: could not find reference to users .  attached @ http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=00187016525356963724&t=0018701652535696372454775

Answer (score 0):

The MQ console can be configured to either check users against the OS users, those defined in its mqwebuser.xml file or LDAP (see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q127970_.htm).

Assuming you're using the Docker configuration from https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-docker, if you look in https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-docker/blob/master/setup-mqm-web.sh you'll see that the container has been configured to use the mqwebuser.xml list for users, not the OS. If you edit this to match the configuration in local_os_registry.xml rather than basic_registry.xml (both referenced in that knowledge center page above) it should give you the right behaviour.